# htaccess to block direct access to images and pdfs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to prevent a user from directly surfing to an image that is on my website.

Example
prevent access 
www.mydomain.com/images/myimg.jpeg
mydomain.com/images/myimg.jpeg

Allow the image to be shown if its being viewed from within my website

```
<img src="www.mydomain.com/images/myimg.jpeg">
<img src="mydomain.com/images/myimg.jpeg">
<img src="/images/myimg.jpeg">
```

I'm confident that its not a cache issue because I'm uploading the image on one computer and trying to call it on another which has never called the image before?.

I'm using this in my .htaccess file but it doesnt appear to be blocking the images?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpg|pdf|jpeg|png)$ - [F]
```

NOTE if I put php as a file type and try and surf to my .php page i get forbidden message I'm hoping to get when trying to directly access an image or pdf.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your second condition is redundant because it's functionally equivalent. You should probably allow empty referer, too. Does the `NS` flag help?

Comment: can you provide a working example of what I should try @Walf

Comment: Can I do your work for you?